# UMBRACO SEO Issues : Multiple Canonical Formats

Tags: .net, seo, umbraco

I am having issues with umbraco (v 4.5.2) and the MS Seo Toolkit.

I get the "this page has multiple canonical formats" error from both the home page and pretty much all the items in the "media" directory.

I saw a guide to address much of this via url rewriting, but that uses IIS 7 and the host I am using uses IIS 6.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I have access to ISAPI_Rewrite (www.helicontech.com) on the server, but can't see any examples or quick start that will point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you mean that its complaining about these URLs both resolving: site.com/about and www.site.com/about?

Comment: Yes, the default home pages has the title "resorts and properties" and so can be accessed via domain.com/ and domain.com/resprts-and-properties.aspx.  The exampels I've seen to address the issue involve IIS7 Url re-wrtiting, which is not an option....

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config change the setting

```
<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="false" />
```

to true.  This will not add the extension .aspx on to all the filename.  Then just make sure you use reference links like this:

```
<a href="/{localLink:1197}" target="_self">
```

where 1197 is replaced by the node id.

Hope that this helps

Comment: I tried this and it seems to actually make every page report as being accessible by both the .aspx and the directory name, effectively extending the problem to every page in the site!  I'm not sure if it is something I am doing, but I'm only using local links and the COG Navigation Module.  Any idea?

Comment: Yes you will still be able to connect via the .aspx but the "umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" tells umbraco only to generate urls without the .aspx on.

Comment: Ah, I had a couple of hard coded links and that was causing the double up.  However, I still get the canonical issue with the main site home page as it has a name "resorts-and-properties" and is the default page.  Any idea how to get passed that WITHOUT IIS 7 url re0write rules?

Comment: Do you have a public URL for the site and I will have a look

Comment: You do not need access to another URL rewriter as the one from urlrewriting.net is bundled in with Umbraco. Its configuration file is located in config/UrlRewriting.config

Comment: From the look of the SEO report all I think you need to do is change the link for "resorts & properties" on the menu bar to point to http://greekoptions.mysolutionuk.com/ rather than http://greekoptions.mysolutionuk.com/resorts-properties

Comment: I've realised that I can use the pageTitle field for the nav menus and page titles (doh).  So yes, I can now rename the Resorts Node to be "default" or /.... that should solve the problem....

Comment: If that does can you up vote my answer and mark it as the accepted anser please? Many thanks

Comment: Hello,  It turns out you can't rename an umbraco node with a blank space to get it to "look" like the / default page.  The answer was to modify the "forcehome" section of the COG:Navigation xslt file so that it outputs just the homeroot url and ignores the node name.  Thanks for your help, while not the direct answer, you comments essentialy gave me the info I needed to solve it!